# I'm on GCS's free trial; how do I increase my storage from 5gb to 25 gb?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So I'm playing around in a notebook that lets me experiment with the T5 model. When I try to fine-tune the model (it has 3B parameters), I get:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:The `3B` model is too large to use with the 5GB GCS free tier. Make sure you have at least 25GB on GCS before continuing.
```

I've been looking around trying to find a way to increase the storage in my bucket, but no luck. Haven't been able to find help on this particular issue. Anyone know how to increase the storage from 5GB to 25 GB in a particular bucket on GCS?

Also worth mentioning: my billing account is tied to the project where the bucket is - so that hasn't seemed to resolve it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud Free Tier has two parts:

- A 12-month free trial with $300 credit to use with any Google Cloud
  services.
- Always Free, which provides limited access to many common
  Google Cloud resources, free of charge.

As part of the **Google Cloud Free Tier**, [Cloud Storage provides](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) resources that are free to use up to specific limits: **Standard Storage - 5 GB-months**

You may want to [upgrade to a paid account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) to use Google Cloud to enjoy the benefits of having more Cloud Storage capacity.

You can upgrade from the free trial to a paid account through the Google Cloud Console. To upgrade your account to a paid account, click the Activate button. If the Activate button is not visible, on the menu bar, click Free trial status Free trial status icon and the Activate button will appear.

You must be a Billing Administrator on the account to make this change.

Google Cloud services charge you only for resources you use. Each service has its own pricing model, which you can find in the documentation for each individual service.